# Insert query values in a cell in iTextSharp

Tags: itext, webmatrix, razor-2

I have managed to generate a pdf using iTextSharp in webmatrix. I have a query shown below:

```
 var db = Database.Open("Northwind");
 var sql = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City, Country, Phone FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'ALFKI'";
var data = db.Query(sql);
```

In my pdf I want to insert the query values where I have marked #query and #query2 in my code.

```
dfPTable nestedb = new PdfPTable(2);
nestedb.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
nestedb.AddCell(new Phrase("Company Name:", arialCertify));
nestedb.AddCell(new Phrase(#query));
nestedb.AddCell(new Phrase("Contact name:", arialCertify));
nestedb.AddCell(new Phrase("#query2", arialCertify));
```

How do I insert the query values in my generated pdf?

Answer (score 2):

As it is now, your process is flawed. You should either:

- create the PDF as a form (getting some kind of template), that you will fill in and flatten after retrieving the data from your database
- retrieve the data beforehand, and generate the PDF on-the-fly directly with that data

Comment: Thank you very much.  With the help of this link http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/205/Exporting-The-Razor-WebGrid-To-PDF-Using-iTextSharp , the pdf was generated on the fly with the data. I am unaware of the syntax to grab my database values and just insert them on appropriate sections in my pdf.

Comment: iterate over the `data` variable, and for each `customer` element, you can access `customer.CompanyName`, `customer.ContactName`

Comment: When I iterate and use customer.CustomerName or data.CustomerName my pdf is not generated meaning an error in my code. Is it possible to provide me with code. My query result is a single record.